# Directory folder named '['

Tags: directory, anaconda

After installing Anaconda my administrative account shows a large folder with the apparent name `[` --without the italics. I uninstalled Anaconda using anaconda clean but the `[` folder wasn't removed and still has thousands of files related to anaconda. I am unsure how to safely remove the files. The system is running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Can I simply rename and / or remove the folder without creating another
problem?

Comment: You probably made a typo in some command and created that directory. What does it contain? Examine your command history as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I simply rename and / or remove the folder without creating another
>   problem?

If you installed Anaconda, and during the install process it created that directory `[`, then yes, you can definitely remove it after uninstalling Anaconda.

> I uninstalled Anaconda using anaconda clean...

I'm not familiar with Anaconda or that command, but to properly uninstall (including all config files) you should use your package manager and not the application itself. `apt-get purge anaconda` (assuming the package installed is named `anaconda`, else change it to match) should completely remove everything. Then you can go back and reinstall later, choosing a different directory name if necessary.